# FetchContent causes errors: Maximum recursion depth of 1000 exceeded

Tags: cmake

Trying to use FetchContent instead of ExternalProject but receive the following error:

> [cmake] CMake Error at vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:147
> (if): [cmake]   Maximum recursion depth of 1000 exceeded

The following is output in the CMakeError.log but it isn't the root error:

> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_0faae && [1/2] Building C
> object CMakeFiles/cmTC_0faae.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o [2/2] Linking
> C executable cmTC_0faae FAILED: cmTC_0faae : &&
> /bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9 -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create
> CMakeFiles/cmTC_0faae.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -o cmTC_0faae
> -lpthreads && : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Currently using CMake 3.20.0 in Ubuntu.  Have tried multiple earlier versions of CMake as well and all have the same error.

I am building the CMake source using the following tutorial:

https://graspingtech.com/upgrade-cmake

Edit:

Full CMakeOutput.log - https://gist.github.com/rschiefer/599055460f231bc71984848ab7a6a302#file-cmakeoutput-log

CMake Output - https://gist.github.com/rschiefer/599055460f231bc71984848ab7a6a302#file-cmake-output

Comment: `CMakeError.log` contains many error messages which are not actually errors and do not prevent the project from configuring. Please, show the error message from the CMake **output**.

Comment: I'll pull the cmake output logs and add them to the question but I did review them and didn't see any other errors there.

Comment: No you need to show NOT the *log*, but the **output**. This is what you see in the terminal when run `cmake` in the command line. Or, if you run CMake via GUI, you could find the output in one of the window's fields(areas).

Comment: BTW, the tutorial linked in your post is not accessible.

Comment: Fixed tutorial link and added CMake terminal output.

Comment: So the error message you got it `CMake Error at vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:147 (if):` and `Maximum recursion depth of 1000 exceeded`. Please, paste it to the question post (as **text**, not as link).

Answer (score 0):

put following lines in your CMakeLists.txt and create build directory again and then generate build files and try again.

```
if(NOT CMAKE_MAXIMUM_RECURSION_DEPTH)
  set(CMAKE_MAXIMUM_RECURSION_DEPTH 2000)
endif()
```